# Error installing arangodb

Tags: database, arangodb

Trying to install arangodb on mint 16.04, I was able to install it but it is giving following error

Setting up arangodb3 (3.2.10) ...
FATAL ERROR: EXIT_FAILED - "exit with error"
dpkg: error processing package arangodb3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 arangodb3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: did you ever resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
sudo dpkg --purge arangodb3
```

Then upgrade your system to check for the same error,

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then reinstall your arangodb3.

It works for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Error?:**  I had a similar issue; i checked https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/7705, raised issue here, where they claim the error is as a result of default configuration of SSE4.2 that clashes with lower CPU types, check the conversation thread:

**Solution ?:** i directly downloaded the .deb file , my specific version was
**arangodb3-3.3.0-1_amd64.deb**(you can play around with the version numbers because the current version is arangodb3-3.9.1-1 ) , then i run the command to install below:

```
sudo dpkg -i arangodb3-3.3.0-1_amd64.deb
```

and on executing the command **arangosh** on the terminal ,wallah!:

```
Please specify a password: 

                                       _     
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __   __ _  ___  ___| |__  
 / _` | '__/ _` | '_ \ / _` |/ _ \/ __| '_ \ 
| (_| | | | (_| | | | | (_| | (_) \__ \ | | |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_| |_|\__, |\___/|___/_| |_|
                       |___/                 

arangosh (ArangoDB 3.3.0 [linux] 64bit, using jemalloc, VPack 0.1.30, RocksDB 5.6.0, ICU 58.1, V8 5.7.492.77, OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017)
Copyright (c) ArangoDB GmbH

Pretty printing values.
Connected to ArangoDB 'http+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529' version: 3.3.0 [server], database: '_system', username: 'root'
```